# SharePoint Service

Tags: 2013, development

I developed a SVC on SharePoint 2013 that uses MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory. The service must generate files. It is a very long operation.
How do I increase the default timeout?

**Updates:**
I have resolved this issue. SPWebApplication has the property named "RequestManagementSettings". I have increased RequestManagementSettings.RequestTimeout. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either in IIS or through the webconfig. Excerpt from [here](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/925083/en-us)

IIS

- Run the IIS Manager
- Right-click the virtual server that you want to configure, and then click Properties.
- Click the Web Site tab.
- Under Connections, type the number of seconds that you want in the Connection time-out box, and then click OK.

WebConfig

- Open the web application Web.config file in Notepad at   Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\VirtualDirectoryFolder
- Change the following line in the file.
- Existing line

  `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />`
- Replacement line

  `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="999999" maxRequestLength="51200" />`

Click File, and then click Save.
Exit Notepad.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it didn't help me. I get 503 error after around 1.5 minutes working of the service.

Comment: You need to do this for every web server in your farm.